# How to give access to programmer/developer to make changes, but prevent undesirable changes?

Tags: permissions, user-access

Is there any way that I can give access to my programmer to make changes but make sure they don't delete stuff it they get upset?

Comment: how about making sure your developer do not get "upset"?

Comment: There is simply no way to do that. A developer needs admin permissions to make changes, and the word `admin` means a person who can administrate and make permanent changes, without restriction.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** as @Mark Kaplun pointed out.

> once you let a developer in there is no way to restrict him. If you don't trust someone for good reason, than don't let him in as there are more than enough privilege escalation exploits going around for him to make himself admin.

So the solution I provided needs *trust*. If you have that covered you may use this. 
**In my experience,** developers are here to help people and they will sometimes play pranks on there clients if they get upset but it never happened to me that my superiors or developers (when I was new to programming just like you) *intentionally* did something that resulted in my loss. 

**Solution:**
Depending upon what you want to allow them and what not, you can download and use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) plugin to create a new `role` with specific capabilities only. 

For example, they can edit posts but cannot delete them. It's a very powerful plugin and can help you solve your problem.

- You can select specifically **what they can** modify and **what they can't**.
- You can **allow** them to **edit**.
- You can **prevent** them from **deleting** anything. Just by removing all the delete permissions from a role.

**Additionally:** 
You can use [Temporary login without password](https://wordpress.org/plugins/temporary-login-without-password/) plugin.
This plugin will allow you to create temporary account which will expire after a certain period of time. This can help you restrict them from accessing and changing anything in future if you forget to delete there user account. 
For example, set the expiration for 1 day and then give them the account. Now after one day they won't be able to login.

**Alternatively:**
If your developer/programmer needs to access your server, you can create a FTP account which can only access certain directories/folder. However this is different from accessing your WordPress Admin.

Comment: once you let a developer in there is no way to restrict him. If you don't trust someone for good reason, than don't let him in as there are more than enough privilege escalation exploits going around for him to make himself admin.

Comment: That's a valid point, I will update my answer.